# Enforcing FIFO delivery of messages in Service Bus topic using sessions

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have one publisher and one consumer for my Service Bus topic. My goal is to make the consumer receive messages in the same order that the publisher published them to the topic. Here is my code to publish messages to a session-enabled topic:

```
public void Publish<T>(T messageObject)
{
    var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(messageObject);
    var message = new ServiceBusMessage(jsonString)
            {
                SessionId = "12345"
            };
    
    message.ApplicationProperties["messageType"] = typeof(T).Name;

    serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(message);
}
```

And here is the code for the receiver:

```
public async Task ReceiveWithSessionsAsync()
{
    var options = new ServiceBusSessionProcessorOptions
    {
        ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete,
        AutoCompleteMessages = true,
        MaxConcurrentSessions = 1,
        MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession = 1,
    };

    await using ServiceBusSessionProcessor processor = serviceBusClient.CreateSessionProcessor("my_topic", "my_subscription__session_enabled", options);

    processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;

    async Task MessageHandler(ProcessSessionMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        var body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
        logger.LogInformation($"received body: {body}");
    }

    // start processing
    await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
}
```

I make several calls to `Publish` and then call `ReceiveWithSessionsAsync`, however, the order of messages received still is not the same order by which they were sent.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Sounds off. Do you have a repro in a public repo?

Comment: @SeanFeldman here you go: https://github.com/rezamanshouri/azure-service-bus

Comment: @SeanFeldman oddly, every time I run the app, the very call to `publish-messages-with-session` results in messages being received in a random order. However, the order seems to be preserved in the subsequent calls. I see the exact behavior with non-session subscription, too.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you constraint `ServiceBusSessionProcessorOptions.SessionIds` to your hard-coded session only, will that work or not?

Comment: @SeanFeldman same thing, added `SessionIds = { "some_session_ID" }` to `ServiceBusSessionProcessorOptions`, and the same behavior as my previous comment.

Comment: I'm wondering why you are not using queue in this scenario?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan bc I have multiple consumers.

Comment: @havij this is the first sentence of your post "I have one publisher and **one** consumer for my Service Bus topic."

Comment: @HamletHakobyan in my application, I have multiple consumers and that's why I need to use a topic. But for the sake of asking this question, I just made it simple to "assume" there is only one consumer, and in the public repo I shared, there's only one consumer as well.

Comment: @SeanFeldman I'd appreciated any help on this, I haven't still figured this out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone else runs into this.

So I realized the problem was not in the consumer since the messages on the Service Bus Explorer showed the messages were in the wrong order.

What I was missing was an `await` on `serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(message)` call, off course without awaiting this async call, the order of messages would be random. SMH!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are accepting the session in your receiver? If you would take a look at [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample03_SendReceiveSessions.md) sample, it calls the "AcceptNextSessionAsync" method before receiving the messages, so make sure you are doing that.

Ps: I'd actually like to submit this as a comment, but I'm not yet able to

Comment: If you look at other examples in that same repo, you'd see there are two ways to consume session messages, one is the one you mentioned, and the other one is the one I am using: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample05_SessionProcessor.md

Answer (score -1):

Try message.setSessionId("12345") in your sender and acquire lock of your session in your receiver.
PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="5.2.0"

```
var options = new ServiceBusSessionProcessorOptions
{
    // By default after the message handler returns, the processor will complete the message
    // If I want more fine-grained control over settlement, I can set this to false.
    AutoCompleteMessages = false,
    // I can also allow for processing multiple sessions
    MaxConcurrentSessions = 5,
    MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession = 2,
    // Processing can be optionally limited to a subset of session Ids.
    SessionIds = { "12345", "67890" },
};

// create a session processor that we can use to process the messages
await using ServiceBusSessionProcessor processor = client.CreateSessionProcessor(queueName, options);
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't work. `SetSessionId` looks like a Java method, not C#, also I have a topic not a queue (in the last line of your code, you are using the method for queues).